# Algorithm to efficiently compute$ A^k$

Tags: matrices, algorithms, asymptotics, linear-programming, svd

If a symmetric matrix $A$ has SVD $A=U\Sigma U^{\top}$, then $A^k=U\Sigma^kU^{\top}$. What would be the most efficient algorithm to compute $A^k$ such that the worst case time complexity is as low as possible?

I am thinking that :
1. Take SVD of $A$
2. Since we know that $A^k=U\Sigma^kU^{\top}$ we can effectively calculate $A^k$ because U is the matrix of eigen vectors of A, each column of U is the eigen vector of A corresponding to each eigen value.

Would this approach be correct ? Or is there a better way.
Also what would be the time complexity of the above method ?

Comment: I guess it depends. Do you start with the SVD given? If so, computing $\Sigma^k$ seems to be optimal. If not and $A$ and $k$ are small, I guess I'd rather just compute $A^k$ directly.

Comment: The SVD is not given, I am looking for an algorithm that makes use of SVD or any relevant property of SVD for real symmetric matrix A

Comment: You can compute the SVD in time $O(n^3)$, which is what the trivial algorithm for computing a square takes. So getting the SVD and then computing powers of $\Sigma$ should be a very good choice. Of course, you can only computs the SVD up to numerical approximations, and this introduces a complication; if you _must_ use SVD, then you are only looking for approximations, though, so this should not be too bad of a problem.

Comment: Note that if you would like to compute $A^k$ directly, you might want to consider a certain ordering of the operations, e.g., $A^4=A(A(AA))=(AA)(AA)$ but the first involves three matrix products while the second only two.